# Find the fourth instance of a line from a text file, then truncate

Tags: python, python-3.x, find, rss, truncate

I'm trying to reformat a RSS file, to which long complex entries are added to the beginning of frequently. I'm quite a noob, and don't know where to begin, so I was looking for a solution on this site, and haven't found it yet. Some of the commands are quite unfamiliar to me, but I have worked with the file quite a bit and downloaded a feed on a schedule.

I'm trying to find the fourth item in the RSS feed (Denoted by the "/item" tag) however, this is where I've hit a snag where I can't find the answer.

(Python 3)

```
import time
import sched
import urllib.request
import shutil
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def rss():
    # Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `file_name`:
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://any.website.here/rss') as response, open('test.xml', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
    print('Updating RSS')
def trunc():
    a = ()
    a = open('test.xml', 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8')
    c = (0)
    for line in a:
        if a.readline() == '</item>':
            c = c+1
            print(c, 'items found!' at )
        if c == 4:
            return a.tell()
    a.seek(0), print(a.read())
    a.close
def scheduler_rss():
    scheduler.enter(0, 1, rss, ())  # calls rss
    scheduler.run()
    trunc()
   #time.sleep(43200) #time in seconds, this is 12 hours
    time.sleep(30)  #Variable for testing

for i in range(100):
    scheduler_rss()
```

This is just the most recent iteration of many failed attempts at finding a solution.

Anyway, this is the RSS I've been wrestling with... http://nightvale.libsyn.com/rss and it does copy the file onto my hard drive as I tell it to, and that file can then be read by an RSS feed reader (In my case a ticker). Basically, I guess I'm asking: how can I find the position in the file to truncate the file from that point on, that point being the fourth time the  tag is invoked in the .xml file, keeping in mind the feed will be updated regularly and this tag won't be in the same position each version?

Comment: There are a tonne of xml parsers if you're interested in making your life easy...

Comment: what do you mean by 'fourth item' ? do you mean you want to extract any text bteween `<link>...</link>` tag ?

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to truncate everything in the file after the 4th item in the file, so there's a header with lots of descriptions (So it varies in length), then it comes to <item> (Various things in here, different # and lengths of lines) </item>. I want 4 sets of <item> ... </item> then truncate the file after the last one. Then I'll append the closing </rss> and whatnot once the file is truncated to only 4 items. As it stands, the file scrolls for like 10 minutes in my ticker, when I only want to be notified of the 4 newest releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in a different approach, here's how you can do this using python's `xml.dom` module. You can just as well do this with `xml.etree`.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
dom = parse('test.xml')

... # download and save your xml
items = dom.getElementsByTagName('item')
for item in items:
    for child in item.childNodes[:4]:
        if len(child.childNodes) > 0:
            print(child.tagName + ':', child.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Prints something like this for every `<item>` tag till the 4th:

```
title: 110 - Matryoshka
pubDate: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 04:00:00 +0000
guid: ef49bfbd9603243db217053194cc2dc0
link: http://nightvale.libsyn.com/110-matryoshka
...
```

---

And now, to truncate all items beyond the 4th element:

```
parentNode = items[0].parentNode    
for i in range(4, len(items)):
    parentNode.removeChild(items[i])

dom.writexml(open('test2.xml', 'w'))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Coldspeed! Thanks for the answer; to integrate it with my scheduler, I just had to put the first and third bit of code into a a 'def' and 'return' after writing it. I added a bit of 'print' so I know what the program is doing and when it's doing it. Being new to the language, it's hard to find which libraries I need, it's like trying to describe a cat without knowing there's a perfectly good word for cat.

Comment: @ThomasLoman I know how you feel. Actually, I'd never used `xml.dom` before, but since I had worked with html DOM, it didn't take long to throw some code together. Anyways, glad to know it worked.